# Reflection - trying to get a reference for class field to pass it as an argument to a function

Tags: java, reflection, reference, field

I'm trying to print public properties of an object which can be primitives or also an object.
by using Reflection I manage to print the methods(getMethods())and primitive fields(getDeclaredFields()) but when I try to send recursively the field of type class(B) I get an error(in line **printProperties(o);**)-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set B field A.b1 to A

my problem is in -

```
else {
                 Object o = f.get(this);
                 printProperties(o);
```

How can I send a references of class B to printProperties in order to go into Class B and print all the properties their etc.. ?

example -

```
public class A {
  public String s1;
  public int 1;
  public B b1;
}
public class B {
  public String s2;
  public int 2;
  public C c1;
}
```

```
public void printProperties(Object reflectObject) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Class reflectClass = (Class) reflectObject;
         String className = reflectClass.getName();
         System.out.println(className);
         Method [] classMethod = reflectClass.getMethods();
         for(Method m :classMethod){
             System.out.println("Name "+m.getName());
             System.out.println("Return "+m.getReturnType());
         }
         System.out.println("Fields");
         Field[] fields = reflectClass.getDeclaredFields();
         for (Field f : fields){
             if(f.getType().isPrimitive()||f.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)){
                 System.out.println("Field "+f.getName());
             }
             else {
                 Object o = f.get(this);
                 printProperties(o);
            }
```

Comment: Hi it’s my first post here.. sorry for the lack of details , I tried to fix it and make it more clear, hope you can manage to help me

Comment: That’s better. The error message is misleading, unfortunately, as it talks about “set” when you are actually doing *get*, that’s an old issue. But the issue is clear. You have a field declared by a certain class but are passing an object of a different class. When you are processing a data structure recursively, you can’t pass `this` all the time. You have to pass the object you are currently processing.

Comment: But there is some confusion about objects and classes here. You are performing a type cast, `(Class) reflectObject` instead of calling `reflectObject.getClass()`. Since this doesn’t fail immediately, you are apparently also not passing the object in the first invocation but a `Class`. But in the recursion, you are trying to pass `o`, which is actually the right approach. But then, you have to fix the first invocation, to pass, e.g. `this` instead of `getClass()` and to replace the cast by reflectObject.getClass()`.

Comment: what do you mean by old issue ? how can I fix it ?

Comment: You don’t need to fix the exception message. Just fix your code so that the exception doesn’t happen. Then, you don’t need to worry about its wrong message.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of `f.get(this)` is that the field’s declaring class in not compatible with the type of `this`. Since you’re recursively traversing fields, you should use the field’s value instead. The next line `printProperties(o);` suggests that you had such an approach in mind. But this contradicts the method’s first line `Class reflectClass = (Class) reflectObject;` The field’s value is not a `Class` object. But the fact that the first invocation did not fail with a `ClassCastException` immediately but reach the `get(this)` point suggests that the initial caller of this method did pass a `Class` object rather than an actual instance.

It is possible to use the declared types only, without runtime objects. If you take this route, you should be consistent and declare the argument as `Class`:

```java
public void printProperties(Class<?> reflectClass) throws IllegalAccessException {
    String className = reflectClass.getName();
    System.out.println(className);
    for(Method m: reflectClass.getMethods()) {
        System.out.println("Name " + m.getName());
        System.out.println("Return " + m.getReturnType());
    }
    System.out.println("Fields");
    for(Field f: reflectClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println("Field " + f.getName());
        Class<?> fieldType = f.getType();
        if(!fieldType.isPrimitive() && fieldType != String.class) {
            printProperties(fieldType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can invoke it with `printProperties(getClass());` or `printProperties(someObject.getClass());` or by specifying the type directly, e.g. `printProperties(A.class);`.

The other approach is to use the actual value and its class. In this case, you have to fix the caller, to pass an object, like `printProperties(this);` or `printProperties(someObject);`. The compiler won’t warn you if you pass a `Class` where an `Object` is expected. In that case, you would be inspecting the class `java.lang.Class`.

```java
public void printProperties(Object reflectObject) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> reflectClass = reflectObject.getClass();
    String className = reflectClass.getName();
    System.out.println(className);
    for(Method m :reflectClass.getMethods()) {
        System.out.println("Name " + m.getName());
        System.out.println("Return " + m.getReturnType());
    }
    System.out.println("Fields");
    for(Field f : reflectClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println("Field " + f.getName());
        Class<?> fieldType = f.getType();
        if(!fieldType.isPrimitive() && fieldType != String.class) {
            Object fieldValue = f.get(reflectObject);
            if(fieldValue != null) printProperties(fieldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the actual value’s type. So when a field refers to an object of a subtype, the subtype will be inspected. On the other hand, this approach can’t inspect `null`. You could combine both approaches, to use the field’s declared type when its value is `null`. That is left as an exercise to the reader. When you are using both methods, it’s recommended to give them different names, to minimize the chances of mixing up `Class` and `Object`.